# SQL Join question, return null if second table is empty

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 tables.

**table 1 (projects): id, name, type**

**table 2 (project_ratings): project_id, rating**

Some projects don't have ratings.

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`name`, AVG(pr.rating) FROM (`projects` p) JOIN `project_ratings` pr ON `p`.`id` = `pr`.`project_id` WHERE `p`.`type` = 'group' OR `p`.`type` = 'user';
```

I want to return all projects, and return NULL if there aren't any ratings. This query returns only the ones with ratings.

I tried left join, right join, full join, still same thing.

Using CodeIgniter Active Records:

```
$this->db->select("p.id, p.name, AVG(pr.rating)");
        $this->db->from('projects p');
        $this->db->join('project_ratings pr', 'p.id = pr.project_id');

        $this->db->where('p.type', 'group');
        $this->db->or_where('p.type', 'user');
$res = $this->db->get();
```

what am I missing?

Comment: This is the definition of a `LEFT JOIN` though I think your use of the `AVG` aggregate isn't going to work for this

Comment: I've tried left join... still returns 1 result.. i want all

Comment: I have a feeling you will need a `GROUP BY p.id, p.name` however I still don't think the third column is going to show the correct values. I may be wrong but too lazy to test this myself

Comment: GROUP BY did the trick.. if you could answer it as a whole answer, i can give you credit :) Thank you

Comment: along with left outer join. forgot to add that

Comment: @tpae See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5864378/sql-join-question-return-null-if-second-table-is-empty/5864448#5864448)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using an aggregate function (`AVG()` in this case), you need to specify a `GROUP BY` clause with the non-aggregate fields, eg

```
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

To ensure all `project` references are present regardless of joined ratings, use a `LEFT JOIN`.

Answer (score 3):

The sql that you want would be

```
         SELECT *
           FROM projects
LEFT OUTER JOIN project_ratings ON projects.id = project_ratings.project_id
```

I'm not certain how to do that with code igniter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->db->select("p.id, p.name, AVG(pr.rating) as average_rating");
$this->db->from('projects p');
$this->db->join('project_ratings pr', 'p.id = pr.project_id', 'left');
$this->db->where('p.type', 'group');
$this->db->group_by('p.id');
$this->db->or_where('p.type', 'user');
$res = $this->db->get();
```

If there is no rating, average_rating will be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Query should be:

```
SELECT `p`.`id`, `p`.`name`, AVG(pr.rating) 
FROM (`projects` p) 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN `project_ratings` pr ON `p`.`id` = `pr`.`project_id` 
WHERE `p`.`type` = 'group' OR `p`.`type` = 'user';
```

(I don't know how to do that in CodeIgniter :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get an outer join by do this:

```
    $this->db->join('project_ratings pr', 'p.id = pr.project_id', 'outer');
```